# Replace int values in string with letters in a column using Python

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a csv file. The data originally is derived from PDF and doing a further analysis on the data, There are certain rows where the extracted data contains letters in place of numbers,

I need instead of numbers the letters of the variables. So trying to replace the int values by the letters

Such as in the following example:

```
col_state

2567i
28981
2534s
0123o
```

in the above table i am looking out to replace (i=1, s=5, o=0)

Expected Output:

```
col_state

25671
28981
25345
01230
```

What i have tried so far:

```
import re
chars_to_remove = ['i', '1', 's', '5', '']
regular_expression = '[' + re.escape (''. join (chars_to_remove)) + ']'

df['col_state'].str.replace(regular_expression, '', regex=True)

print(df['HSN_Code'])
```

So I have no clue how to handle this problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
repl = {'i':'1', 's':'5', 'o':'0'}
df['col_state'] = df['col_state'].replace(repl, regex=True)
```

Output:

```
  col_state
0     25671
1     28981
2     25345
3     01230
```

Answer (score 4):

You might use `translate` method as follows

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.Series(["2567i","28981","2534s","0123o"])
t = str.maketrans("iso","150")
data = data.str.translate(t)
print(list(data))
```

output

```
['25671', '28981', '25345', '01230']
```

Explanation: `translate` is useful when you need replace single characters using other single characters, `str.maketrans` when using in 2-argument form create replacement table so i-th element of 1st argument is replaced using i-th element of 2nd argument (arguments must be equal length) which is then usable in `translate`. `translate` is method of `str`s and can be used without `pandas`.